# What is the Fourier transform of the function $e^{-i\pi t^2}\chi_{[-1/2,1/2]}(t)$ where $\chi$ is the characteristic function?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Consider the function $t \mapsto e^{-i\pi t^2}\chi_{[-1/2,1/2]}(t)$ where $\chi$ is the characteristic function. I'm trying to get a formula for the Fourier transform of this function, i.e. I nee to evaluate the integral
$$
\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} e^{-i\pi t^2} e^{-2\pi i k t} \, dt
$$
where $k \in \mathbb R$. I don't really have an approach to evaluate this integral. Someone has an idea?

Comment: Heard of the ErrorFunction?

Answer (score 1):

Complete the square:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} e^{-i\pi t^2} e^{-2\pi i k t} \, dt &= 
\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} e^{-i\pi t^2 -2\pi i k t} \, dt
\\ & = 
e^{i \pi k^2}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} e^{-i\pi(t^2 + 2k t + k^2)} \, dt
\\ & = 
e^{i \pi k^2}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} e^{-i\pi(t+k)^2} \, dt
\\ & = 
e^{i \pi k^2}\int_{-1/2 + k}^{1/2 + k} e^{-i\pi\tau^2} \, d\tau
= 
e^{i \pi k^2}\int_{(-1/2 + k)/\sqrt{\pi}}^{(1/2 + k)/\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-i\tau^2} \, d\tau.
\end{align}
$$
This last integral can be expressed in terms of the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).